# Activities or fragments in Android?

Tags: android

Im creating an app with an action bar, and the tabs go to different web pages. When the user clicks on a different tab I want the previous tabs web page to stay in the same state (ie not reload when the tab is pressed again).

Whats the best way to do this? Separate activities? Fragments? Multiple web views in one activity?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tabs in the ActionBar, which allows you to use Fragments. When changing tabs, the Fragments will replace, and the previous Fragment will hold its contents.

See [Action Bar - Adding Navigation Tabs | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)

Comment: Thanks I've tried this, but I cant get a web view in a fragment, it just opens a separate browser and the tabs disappear.

Comment: How do you fill your webview ?

Comment: Your fragment has an onCreateView() method to create its view.  You can make the WebView a static member of the Fragment class (as an example), this way you'll create the WebView once and it will remain instantiated and with its same state independent of the lifetime of instances of the fragment.

Comment: Yes, but it takes over the whole page, and I lose my tabs. Any ideas?

Comment: Your tab fragments should have a TabListener that is performing the fragment add/remove operations.  There is only one Activity.  That you're losing your ActionBar indicates you might be starting a new Activity?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use one webview and [store content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598273/how-i-can-save-webview-contents-to-show-even-when-no-network-available) of each page locally for example in DB and then make yourself some navigation bar and reload your webview content by navigation bar.
For example navigation bar can be orginized like LinearLayout with Buttons childs.
If you use this way - for example you can download 10 web pages at home with your wi-fi and then minimize your app and go for a walk and after some time (even if you use other apps) you can restore all your information from DB, but if you use only fragments in tabs you can loose you pages because of memory lack.

If you use fragments or atcitvities in tab - you can't be sure that previous content will be saved (but you can still do it by adapter and tabhost (there are quite enough samples how to use fragments + tabs)

PS. this is only my opinion and i haven't tried it yet, but i think local store is a best way to resolve your problem.