# Saving WebView and showing it while offline?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-websettings

I need to cache a WebView in a way that it would use cache if there is no internet, and when there is internet it will use the online page. Since my class with the WebView does loadUrl() in the onCreateView, it reloads it every time so I need cache for 2 reasons: faster loading, but mainly for offline use of the app.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {
    private WebView webView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_layout, container, false);
        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendarWebView);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getContext().getCacheDir().getPath());
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                webView.loadUrl("https://calendar.google.com/calendar/htmlembed?src=wlmacci%40gmail.com&ctz=America%2FToronto");
        //webView.loadUrl("https://sites.google.com/view/wlmac/textfile?");
        //webView.loadUrl("https://google.ca");
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I have tried the `LOAD_DEFAULT` as well as `LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK` and neither seem to work; when I switch away from Calendar fragment and back to it with my WiFi off, I get `net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`

Update: Doesn't work with `LOAD_CACHE_ONLY` either

Update: Added `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` and `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`, am now getting `net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED` error

Sources I learned it from: 
[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607655/saving-webview-page-to-cache)
[Source 2](https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2016/01/android-how-to-use-caching-in-webview.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebView load website when online, load local file when offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670638/webview-load-website-when-online-load-local-file-when-offline)

Comment: No I have already incorporated everything and tried all cache modes yet it still does not work

Comment: enable javascript and try again

Comment: Added JavaScript and other booleans and still doesn't work, check updated code

Answer (score 0):

Add these permissions to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Try this code,

```
webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendarWebView);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 8 * 1024 * 1024 ); 
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( 
getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); 

if ( !isNetworkAvailable() )  //offline
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY );


webView.loadUrl( "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/htmlembed? 
src=wlmacci%40gmail.com&ctz=America%2FToronto" );
```

Network connectivity checking method

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( 
CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried this. I have the permissions already. getApplicationContext() doesn't work and says "Cannot resolve method getApplicationContext()" and same thing goes for the isNetworkAvailable(), it also can't resolve.

Comment: you need to add that method in your class, `isNetworkAvailable`

Comment: Oh yes my bad. What about the getApplicationContext()?
Also shouldn't it not make a difference for checking the network? It is already set to LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK so it should still work. Anyways I will add the method, meanwhile what about the getApplicationContext()?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by that? Also getSystemService() cannot be resolved

Comment: I did getContext() instead of getApplicationContext() do you think that's fine?

Comment: What did you change? The edit shows you replaced the same code

Comment: getApplicationContext() and getSystemService() both remain unresolved

Comment: Remove which line? I cannot just remove the line, it will not work

Comment: So I can use getContext() instead of getApplicationContext() correct?

Comment: context.getSystemService

Comment: context. Doesn't work, I did getContext(). It compiles, but when I open with WiFi, switch fragments, turn WiFi off and then go back to it, I get the "net::ERR_CACHE_MISS" error inside the WebView