# Convert web based database management application into mobile app to make it work offline

Tags: android, laravel, webview, uiwebview, android-webview

We have no knowledge of mobile applications. We need to convert a basic web-based database management application in Laravel into a mobile application. Is there a way to do it without having mobile application developers. The application has the following views
1. Form
2. Edit form
2. All forms
3. Users
4. Edit Users
There are two user type - Admin and data entry operator

Comment: You can load the your website URL into the web view of android app and it will works

Comment: Will it work offline also. If yes, can you tell me or share a link on how to do it

Comment: Let me wrap it up. Its not possible.

Comment: @ChintanSoni not even through web view? Does any web view app works offline?

Comment: Webview is just like any web browser. You can load any url if network connection is available. But it can't work offline.

Comment: It's not like webview cannot work offline, maybe in this case it can't because access to the database is needed. [WebView load website when online, load local file when offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670638/webview-load-website-when-online-load-local-file-when-offline).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using [webview](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview). Start a project in android studio, create a class extending from [Activity](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/android/activity.html), a xml [layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout) file in res/layout, and take a look on your [AndroidManifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) file in the manifests folder.

It will look more or less like this: [image]

The image also shows you the basic structure of the activity, though you don't really need the onCreateOptionsMenu part. Now to make the webview put this in the xml:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

And call it on your onCreate method like the one shown in the image:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com"); //change the link to your
```

In your manifest add permission for the application to use internet:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

If you want to make your webview work offline you could use [webview cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607655/saving-webview-page-to-cache).

But since it is a database managing application, you probably will need to make a full app, and for that you will need an mobile developer. But you could use other approaches, like using [xamarin](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin), [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) or other transpilers, though that will still require learning, it is easier for programmers of other areas to adapt, then maybe you could avoid hiring a mobile programmer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this out and let you know.